# (WP) Code works in standalone codepen, but not on live site

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'm working on a gallery of sorts in Wordpress right now and I'm a bit stuck.

The idea is to change the post thumbnail on hover. The replacement image will be coming from a field generated by the Advanced Custom Fields plugin.

Now, I've managed to pull in both URLs and stored them in variables, but I still won't work. It works on a standalone CodePen, but not on the Wordpress site itself.

**Wordpress code:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 

var firstthumb = '<?php echo the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>';
var secondthumb = '<?php if( get_field('multiple_thumbs') ): ?><?php echo the_field('multiple_thumbs'); ?><?php endif; ?>';

jQuery('.member-thumbnail').hover(function() {
jQuery('.attachment-thumbnail').attr('src', secondthumb);
}, function() {
jQuery('.attachment-thumbnail').attr('src', firstthumb);
    });
});
```

And it returns this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  var firstthumb = 'http://www.cozeh.com/wp2/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/pic2.png';
  var secondthumb = 'http://www.cozeh.com/wp2/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/multiple2.png';

  jQuery('.member-thumbnail').hover(function() {

    jQuery('.attachment-thumbnail').attr("src", secondthumb);
  }, function() {
    jQuery('.attachment-thumbnail').attr("src", firstthumb);
  });
});
```

Here's a link to the [beta version](http://www.cozeh.com/wp2/team/).
And here's the [codepen](http://codepen.io/moetendencia/pen/VedLJK).

Would appreciate any explanation as to why this doesn't work or if you have any alternative solutions.

Edit: Updated code

Comment: Try removing `echo` from in front of `the_post_thumbnail_url()`...That function already displays the URL. I'm also not sure what you're doing with `if( get_field('multiple_thumbs') ):`...That definitely doesn't return a URL

Comment: Must have overlooked the multiple_thumbs while copy-pasting.Fixed now.

Removed `echo`, but still doesn't work.

Comment: not sure why you'd go such trouble, why not just use pure CSS? you can have the second image position in absolute and hidden or display none or 0 opacity by default with z index larger than first image then change its property when parent element is hovered covering the first image. ;)

Comment: @silver When my brain doesn't work at 1 in the morning, I tend to forget that the simpler solution, the better. lol thanks for the input. Will keep in mind next time :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in the codepen you are not wrapping the `img` in an `a` tag, but you are doing it on the WordPress site. So to make it work in wordpress you need to remove the link that is wrapping the image or change you jQuery code, replacing this code:

```
jQuery('.member-thumbnail').hover(function() {
...
});
```

To this one:

```
jQuery('.member-thumbnail a').hover(function() { 
...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Marking as solved.

Turns out it wasn't a script issue after all.

WP 4.4.+ was appending `srcset`to the images as part of their move to make all images responsive. The `img src`was changing but not the `srcset`hence the problem.

Found a workaround to disabling the responsive images for now.

And I edited the code so it only affects one of the thumbnails, not every single one.

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>

    <div class="member-<?php the_ID(); ?>-thumbnail">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?></a>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    var firstthumb = '<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>';
    var secondthumb = '<?php if( get_field('multiple_thumbs') ): ?><?php echo the_field('multiple_thumbs'); ?><?php endif; ?>';

    jQuery('.member-<?php the_ID(); ?>-thumbnail').hover(function() {
    jQuery('.member-<?php the_ID(); ?>-thumbnail .attachment-thumbnail').attr('src', secondthumb);
    }, function() {
    jQuery('.member-<?php the_ID(); ?>-thumbnail .attachment-thumbnail').attr('src', firstthumb);
    });
});

</script>
```

Thanks for the input everybody.